# Duplicate entry sql when loading initial data for sql database -Springboot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I had this kind of error when add value to sql database.

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [data.sql]: INSERT INTO `Tax` VALUES (1,'0',3,6); nested exception is java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'Tax.PRIMARY'
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [data.sql]: INSERT INTO `Tax` VALUES (1,'0',3,6); nested exception is java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'Tax.PRIMARY'
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'Tax.PRIMARY'
```

When i change the ID to 2 (primary key) , the problem it fix for mvn clean package. However when i run java . jar file the problem appear again and state '' Duplicate entry '2' ". How can i  fix this problem

**schema.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS  `Tax` (

    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

    `taxable_income` CHAR(50) NOT NULL,

    `addition_charge` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
    
    `charge_every_one_dollar` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
   
    primary key (`id`)
);
```

**data.sql**

```
INSERT INTO `Tax` VALUES  
   (1,'0',3,6);
```

Comment: You try to insert id 1 on every startup, and since it's unique you fail. You can change the insert to on duplicate do nothing..

Answer (score 2):

Since the `id` is already `AUTO_INCREMENT`, you can fix it simply by not defining the `id` when inserting:

```
INSERT INTO `Tax`(`taxable_income`, `addition_charge`, `charge_every_one_dollar`) 
VALUES  
   ('0',3,6);
```

The `id` column will automatically add itself based on last `AUTO_INCREMENT` value. You can check that by running:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `Tax`;
+-------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                     |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------+
|  Tax  | CREATE TABLE `Tax` (                             |
|       |  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,               |
|       |  `taxable_income` char(50) NOT NULL,             |
|       |  `addition_charge` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,        |
|       |  `charge_every_one_dollar` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,|
|       |  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)                              |
|       |  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3                |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------+
                                        ^^^^
                                     this is the last value
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b8116b4095ca2c971ea28dc138c9686f)